# How to change ActionBarSherlock Tab Text color?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

```
adapter.addTab(getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Tab-1"),
                Tab1.class, null);
adapter.addTab(getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Tab-2"),
                Tab2.class, null);
adapter.addTab(getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Tab-3"),
                Tab3.class, null);
```

As of now every Tab has its TextColor as white. I want it to be grey when not selected and white on selected. So, how can i change the text color in **onTabSelected** or **onTabUnselected**.

Or should i go with setCustomView for the tab?? Here again the TextSize and all needs to be taken care of

```
<style name="my_ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_wicfy</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_wicfy</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

i tried to use

```
<item name="textColor">@color/black</item>
```

but it gives me error that **textColor** is not a valid attribute

Thank You

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should not change text color from the code. Use [color state list resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) instead.

Define the color selector in resources. Define a xml file in `res/color/` directory. The file will contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- use when selected -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#fff" />

    <!-- otherwise use -->
    <item android:color="#888" />
</selector>
```

And then set the text color in a style:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color_selector</item>
```

**Edit:**

You have to set the text color in the right place in the styles! Set the textColor in `(android:)actionBarTabTextStyle`. The theme has to contain:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <!-- define text style for tabs -->
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Then set the text color in the tab text style:

```
<style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText" >
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color_selector</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Like the 1 in the questions?

Comment: You have to add it to `res/color` and reference it as `@color/tab_text_indicator`. You can't use a drawable when a color is expected.

Comment: But the idea is to change the color. So i must use a selector right?? which will be a drawable. if i am using a color that would appear what ever the state is.

Comment: Besides drawable selectors Android has color selectors. `textColor` item expects color or color selector. Read about [color selectors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) in the docs.

Comment: Instead of color selector, i just used **@color/black**. as edited in the question, but the Tab Text color is still **white**

Comment: Uff. To set tab text color you have to set `android:textColor` in `(android:)actionBarTabTextStyle`. You keep placing it at wrong places.