# How to change TabWidget color?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget, android-style-tabhost

I'm new to Android and I need your help!
I love default tabWidget style, but I need white color in tab title.
This is what I have for now
[image: tabwidget]
I want "TAB1" and "TAB2" in white color.
I tried my own tabwidget style. Here's the code

```
<!-- styles.xml -->

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/LightTabWidget</item>
</style>
<style name="LightTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tabTitle</item>
</style>
```

This will change title text color but it change all tab style
[image]

How I can change text color only? Without changing the rest? 
Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE**
I'm using tabHost. Is it possible to do what I need with it not with TabLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put these lines in your xml-

```
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black"

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. But can I do the same with tabHost? Not TabLayout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533061/android-tabhost-change-text-color-style

Comment: Thanks. I tried to find solution without coding but perhaps it's impossible.

Answer (score 3):

> Inside your onCreate or onCreateView try this it worked for me!

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab_bhishilayout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("OPEN"));
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.RED);//set tab indicator color
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLACK));//set tab text color
```

> You may change color of Tabhost text as follow.

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

        for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); // unselected
            TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); //Unselected Tabs
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }

        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF")); // selected
        TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))

    }
});
```

Comment: It's working, but can I achieve same affect with tabHost?

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's impossible without some coding.