# background color of tabs widget

Tags: android, xml

How can I change the display color of tab widget layout screen? Currently it's white. I want to change it to blue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/mainLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ff2356bf" >
        <FrameLayout  android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:layout_weight="0.0" />
        <TabWidget android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.0" />
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@id/pager" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
        <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/BannerLayout" android:paddingBottom="2.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@id/adView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ads:adSize="BANNER" ads:adUnitId="@string/banner" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android tabhost change text color style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533061/android-tabhost-change-text-color-style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/38835247/4758255 [@will-molter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6461642/will-molter) answer:

This can actually be done using XML themes.  The `TabWidget` uses `android:textColorPrimary` for the selected tab and `android:textColorSecondary` for the unselected ones.  Thus, you can achieve a text color change like this:

In styles.xml:

```
<style name="TabWidgetTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/your_primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/your_secondary_color</item>
</style>
```

In your layout:

```
<TabHost
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/TabWidgetTheme"/>
```

Note that the `android:theme` should not be directly in the `TabWidget` itself, but rather the containing `TabHost` or similar.