# Android TabHost Text Colour

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

How can I change the text colour of the tabs within the tabhost. Seems to be a little awkward. Thanks in advance.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.tabdemo.MainActivity" 
        android:background="#00496b"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF">


        <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                 >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   >

                </TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Would prefer to do it via XML opposes to programmaticly - but if there is no other way.

Comment: Possible answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38835247/5115097

Comment: Thanks for this but did not work for me - need the tab heading to be white - not textfield